# Extra newline in output when adding strings

Tags: python

I have a text file something like,

```
3 forwhomthebelltolls
-6 verycomplexnumber
```

The question is, if the integer *K* is positive, take the first *K* characters and put them at the end of the string. If it's negative, take the last *K* characters and put them at the front of the string. Like this:

```
whomthebelltollsfor
numberverycomplex
```

My code is

```
file = open("tex.txt","r")

for line in file:
    K, sentence = int(line.split(" ")[0]), line.split(" ")[1]
    new_sentence = sentence[K:] + sentence[:K]
    print(new_sentence)
```

however it prints the values like:

```
whomthebelltolls
for
numberverycomplex
```

I do not understand why this happens. I am just adding two strings however in printing part the second part that I add goes down.

Comment: is it because your sentence included the `\n`?

Comment: The lines you read from the file will end with a newline character (except possibly the very last line in the file).  You need to strip that off before doing further processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *actual* contents of the file:

```
3 forwhomthebelltolls\n
-6 verycomplexnumber
```

When you iterate through the file with `for line in file`, you're taking the *entire* line, including the newline character at the end. You're never removing that. And so, `sentence[K:]` resolves to `whomthebelltolls\n`, and `sentence[:k]` resolves to `for`. The entire string is `whomthebelltolls\nfor`. Since there's a newline in the middle of the string, that gets printed.

To fix this, strip the string first:

```
for line in file:
    K, sentence = int(line.split(" ")[0]), line.split(" ")[1].strip()
    ...
```

Comment: And we don't actually need to call `line.split()` twice

Comment: I kind of thought that, its (\n) the problem however I couldn't figure out how to solve it. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 4):

if you iterate over a file line-by-line, each line will contain the trailing newline, so in the first iteration `line` is really `forwhomthebelltolls\n`

now when you construct the `new_sentence` you do:

```
 new_sentence = 'forwhomthebelltolls\n'[3:] + 'forwhomthebelltolls\n'[:3]
              =    'whomthebelltolls\n'     + 'for'
              = 'whomthebelltolls\nfor'
```

which prints as:

```
whomthebelltolls
for
```

to get rid of the trailing newline, use `.strip()` (as in `line=line.strip()`)

Comment: so I should use strip in general to get rid of the ("\n") character ?

Comment: yep. although `strip()` will strip away all whitespace (blanks, tabs, newlines,...) on both the beginning and the end of the string. which might be exactly what you want....or too much (depending on your actual use case)